# Markov Chain order 1 vs. AR(1) .... Difference and Implication for Parameter Estimation

Tags: markov-process, autoregressive

As other posts on this site indicate, the difference between a time-homogeneous Markov Chain of order 1 and an AR(1) model is merely the assumption of i.i.d. errors, an assumption that we make in AR(1) but not in a Markov Chain of order 1.

What are the implications of this assumption of i.i.d. errors in the estimation of the population parameters in an AR(1) model vs. in a time-homogeneous Markov Chain of order 1? What methods are used to estimate the population parameters? How do these estimation methods differ due to the assumption of i.i.d. errors made in the AR case but not in the Markov case?

Comment: It depends on what precisely is assumed about the error in the AR(1) case. E.g. if a GARCH(p,q) is assumed, this can be incorporated in maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Richard. That's helpful. I am hoping someone can maybe list a few of the most common/interesting assumptions that can be made about the error in the AR(1) case and link them to the estimation methods that would be used in each of those cases.